Link to Previous, Next, Last files in a directory in PHP
I'm adding webcomics I've created to my static website (PHP and HTML).  Each webcomic has its own directory, complete with pages, images, and a php file (nav2.php) for navigation that is included twice on every page (above and below the comic).
Inside that nav2.php navigation file is where all my trouble lies.  The Previous, Next, and Last links have been the bane of my existence for the past few days.  I've scoured StackOverflow for every solution, and I cannot seem to get this working. I'm sure it must be something stupid, but I'm better at art than code.
Here's what I have now:
<div class="nav2">
<ul>
    <li id="1stcomic"><a href="comic0001.php"><img src="first.webp" alt="first"></a></li>
    <li id="prevcomic"><?php 
        $page = dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'.php';

        $files = glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/comic*.php');

        $currentIdx = array_search($page, $files);

        $prevIdx = $currentIdx - 1;

        if (isset($files[$prevIdx]))
        {
            $prevFile = $files[$prevIdx];
            $prev = pathinfo($prevFile, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            echo '(prev): <a href="'.$prev.'">'.$prev.'</a>';
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "No previous file";
        }
    ?></li>

    <li id="nextcomic"><?php 
        $page = dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'.php';

        $files = glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/comic*.php');

        $currentIdx = array_search($page, $files);

        $nextIdx = $currentIdx +1;

        if (isset($files[$nextIdx]))
        {
            $nextFile = $files[$nextIdx];
            $next = pathinfo($nextFile, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            echo '(next): <a href="'.$next.'">'.$next.'</a>';
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "No next file";
            echo $nextIdx;
            echo $page;
        }
    ?></li>
    <li id="lastcomic">
        <?php
            $lastfiles = scandir("*.php");
            $clast_file = $lastfiles[0];
            echo "<a href=\"$clast_file\"><img src=\"last.webp\" alt=\"Last\"></a>";
        ?>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>


First: Works
Previous: "No previous file" (Can't find the file)
Next: Pulls up the 2nd php file in the directory (comic0002.php in this test) on every page.
Last: Links to the active/current page on every page.

The filenames will all be in alphanumeric order with a common naming convention in each directory.
Example:

/mspaint/comic0001.php, comic0002.php, comic0003.php, comic0004.php
(these are the sample files I'm using)
/sargon/2005-01-07.php, 2005-01-14.php, 2005-01-28.php...

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I've spent a lot of time trying out and modifying previous solutions; and I've had no luck at all.

So every page/folder has it's own copy of "nav2.php" in it?

Only every folder has its own copy of nav2.php.  Every page will use a php include to refer to the common nav2.php in its directory.

Is there a reason why you can't share a global file for that. include ../nav2.php or something? Sorry, I know this might not be what your specific problem is about, but if I'm understanding this correctly I'd nip this in the bud now.

Or, maybe I'm misunderstanding, now that I'm re-reading this.

Try this. Make a PHP file that is not in a dedicated comic folder, like in the root of your site maybe, and include the contents of the: https://3v4l.org/Jqesd. Use require_once on each of your comic.php files and point to this file. Then in those files use $nav = get_nav(__FILE__);. You should be able to use the $nav variable then.

glob should return an array containing only the file names here, without any path prefix. But $page is prefixed with the path to the current directory, so I doubt $currentIdx = array_search($page, $files); ever finds a match here to begin with.

Chris, it's probably something I'm doing wrong, but wherever I put the
$nav = get_nav(__FILE__);
the webpage stops loading.

CBroe, I'm somewhat of a novice when it comes to this stuff.  Is there a better alternative for the array_search then?
